# Approximation theorem for compact operators - a question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

I have some trubles with Approximation Theorem for Compact Operators. I study a proof from Zeidler's book. Can you tell me  how to deduce that dim$(span\,P_n(M))<\infty$? Below, I enclose the proof from the book.[image]

[image]

Comment: It's by definition. $P_n(x)\in\operatorname{span}\{y_1,\ldots,y_N\}$.

Comment: I think so. Aslo, $N=N(n)$ I quess

Comment: Sure, $N$ depends on $n$.